# How to write promise chain with an if condition as the first statement?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

Typically i would do something like this

```
  createQueue(sqs, queueName)
    .then(url => {
      return enqueue(sqs, url, message)
    })
    .then(messageId => {
      return res.status(HttpStatus.OK).send({ id: messageId })
    })
    .catch(err => {
      return handleErr(res, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, err)
    })
```

But in this case I have an `if` check if the url exists and if not i want to call `createQueue`, but in both cases, i want to call the rest of the promise chain.

What is the best way to do this?

```
// This doesn't work
if (!req.queueUrl) {
  return createQueue(sqs, queueName)
}
  .then(url => {
    const myUrl = req.queueUrl || url
    return enqueue(sqs, myUrl, message)
  })
  .then(messageId => {
    return res.status(HttpStatus.OK).send({ id: messageId })
  })
  .catch(err => {
    return handleErr(res, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, err)
  })
```

**Note** This is how i've solved this in the past

```
const promises = []
if (!req.queueUrl) {
  promises.push(createQueue(sqs, queueName))
}
Promise.all(promises)
  .then(url => {
    const myUrl = req.queueUrl || url
    return enqueue(sqs, myUrl, message)
  })
  .then(messageId => {
    return res.status(HttpStatus.OK).send({ id: messageId })
  })
  .catch(err => {
    return handleErr(res, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, err)
  })
```

Comment: What is the rest of the chain expecting as `url` if you *do* have `queueUrl`? Maybe `(req.queueUrl ? Promise.resolve(req.queueUrl) : createQueue(sqs, queueName)).then(...);`?

Comment: hmm good question. let me update.

Comment: You could hide that condition inside a function that either returns `createQueue(...)` or `Promise.resolve(req.queueUrl)`. OR start using `async/await`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Abstract with a function to check and resolve with URL if exist or create new if not. Return `getQueueURL` if required.

```
function getQueueURL(queueURL) {
    if (!queueURL) {
        return createQueue(sqs, queueName);
    }

    return Promise.resolve(queueURL);
}

getQueueURL(req.queueUrl)
    .then(URL => enqueue(sqs, URL, message))
    .then(messageId => res.status(HttpStatus.OK).send({ id: messageId }))
    .catch(error => handleErr(res, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, error))
```

Answer (score 2):

Chain of a dummy promise that resolves the url where you can flip it to the `createQueue` if you need. I'm still unsure what you mean by queueUrl vs url though.

```
var startPromise = Promise.resolve(req.url);
if (!req.queueUrl) {
    startPromise = createQueue(sqs, queueName)
}
return startPromise.then(url => {
        return enqueue(sqs, url, message)
    })
    .then(messageId => {
        return res.status(HttpStatus.OK).send({
            id: messageId
        })
    })
    .catch(err => {
        return handleErr(res, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, err)
    })
```

Comment: `req.queueUrl` is set in a middleware now. I'm trying to refactor this to use that if it exists, otherwise create a queue.